# in_array() with associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get the values out of my email whitelist I've created and compare them to when users use the emails contained in the whitelist during registration.

The array looks like so:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => @hca.com ) [1] => Array ( [email] => @hospitaldatasolutions.com ) )
```

My code:

```
$test = '@hca.com';
$get_whitelist = $mysqli->query('SELECT email FROM email_whitelist');
$white_list_arr = mysqli_fetch_all($get_whitelist, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if(in_array($test, $white_list_arr, true) == true){
print_r($white_list_arr);}
```

The if statement is currently returning false, when that string does exist inside the array. That array above appears multidimensional and I have a feeling that is the reason why in_array is not working, but I'd like to have a second opinion. I read about "nesting it further" in another post but I didn't really understand what that meant.

::EDIT::

This was the correct answer:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem now? Are you trying to check if your value is in all your e-mails, which you received from your query?

Comment: @Rizier123 when a user registers with an email in the whitelist they are accepted by the system (in theory). So this whitelist is supposed to be compared against their registration email AT registration. This is just a test to see if the compare function is working. As you can see I am just testing it against a value that I know is in the array. So my issue that it is returning false and not printing the array like the IF statement should. It is telling me that '@hca.com' is not in the array,

Comment: I still don't really see what you are looking for now: `if(in_array($test, array_column($white_list_arr, "email"))){` <- This maybe ?

Comment: The comment about "nesting it further" was probably sarcasm. If it is simply a list of domains, why do you need nested arrays?  Just do `array('@foo.com', '@bar.com', '@baz.com')` and you're done.

Comment: @SeanBright the issue was when I pulled the associated array from the database, it wasnt simply just emails. It included the [#] key with it and that was causing the array to have a sub-array per key. This could be fixed with either my code I edited above or by designating a new array and looping through the `$white_list_arr['email']` to create the array that you have stated. With the second option, in_array() by itself would work. It was give or take, though I don't know which is more efficient. Thanks for the help. Problem has been solved.

Comment: Please, add yourown answer and check it instead of edition your question.